# Getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView in spring framework using Websphere environment

Tags: spring-mvc

I am facing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView while hitting my JSP page. I have added all the required Jars in WEB-INF/lib folder and also in class-path (META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file) but it does not resolve error.

**My WEB.XML is** -->

```
<servlet id="Servlet_13">
<servlet id="Servlet_13">
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.spg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 

    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/spring.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/spring.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
```

**My Spring-Servlet.XML is -->**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.polaris.*" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
        <value>="/" </value>
        </property> 

        <property name="suffix"> 
        <value>=".jsp" </value>
        </property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

My Java class file is -->

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/BackValuedOffsetChangeEvent.spg")

public class BackValuedOffsetChangeEventAO
{ 

@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })

    public ModelAndView execute (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@Validated @ModelAttribute("BackValuedOffsetChangeEvent")        BackValuedOffsetChangeEvent BackValuedOffsetChangeEvent)
    throws Exception {

// My code
return (new ModelAndView("Success", modelMap));

}
}
```

Spring Jars added are -->
spring-aop-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-expression-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar

Please note application (EAR file) is deployed on WebSphere environment and Getting Dispatcher class which is in the same Jar file but getting an exception for Model-view class.

Please help to find out the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is got resolved after adding JARS in shared Library on Websphere console. Now, it is getting all required JARS. But yet not sure why it is not getting JARS from WEB-INF/lib.